# ESP32 and moisture sensor transistor switch

Tags: esp32, transistors, resistors

I'm doing the classic water moisture sensor project with my ESP32, but I want to be able to switch the sensor on and off since that will reduce the amount of corrosion that occurs.  Can I use a BC547 transistor as suggested below to achieve turning using GPIO18?

[image]

I've also wired an LED in series to show when it's reading/not reading. Would I need the resistor if I didn't have this LED?

Please be easy on me - I'm a beginner to all of this.

**CORRECTIONS (and removed the led):**

[image]

Comment: Your transistor is upside down! The emitter should be on the low (GND) side. You also can't put the LED in the same path as the GND of the sensor. The LED and the 220 ohm resistor will interfere with the supply current of the sensor. Remove them both and add a resistor of about 2.2K ohm between the base of the BC547 and D18. You can turn on/off the LED with another pin if you need an indicator.

Comment: @StarCat thanks. I've removed the LED and fixed the transistor. Why does one need a resistor between the pin and transistor base?  And why 2.2K ohm?

Comment: Your schematic looks correct now. The 2.2K resistor is for limiting the current going through the transistor's base, coming from the GPIO pin (GPIO current will be around  (3.3V - 0.7) / 2200 = 1.2mA), while still providing enough current through the transistor (which is >50-100 x base current). As the sensor requires around 35mA this should be enough. The value of the resistor is not critical.

Comment: You comment and answer explain a lot - thank you

Comment: you can power the sensor from a GPIO, which makes it a lot simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proposed setup will not work, but the second (corrected) one will. Here are some issues in the first setup:

1. Your NPN transistor is upside down. The emitter needs to be connected to GND and the collector to the GND pin of the sensor (the current path is from the sensor to GND).
2. You can't put the LED and the resistor in the GND supply path of the sensor. They will prevent the sensor from getting the needed supply voltage between the Vcc and GND pins.

The solution would be to put the BC547 in the right way, remove the LED and 220 Ohm resistor in the GND path and put a resistor of around 2.2K between D18 and the base of the transistor. The 2.2K resistor is for limiting the base current from the GPIO pin while assuring enough current can flow through the transistor.

This way, your transistor can switch the GND current to the sensor on and off freely. If you need an indicator, you can use a different GPIO pin, and LED and a resistor to provide it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn9cAF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I've wired it up just like this and I'm getting a very high reading when D18 is LOW.  Is this due to D21 becoming a floating pin when the sensor isn't powered?