# How to switch a SIM800L modem on/off with an ESP32-CAM, without a relay?

Tags: mosfet, esp32

I would like to turn a SIM800L modem on/off (to save battery), controlled with GPIO 16 on an ESP32-CAM, without a relay.

It was working OK with an electromagnetic relay, but I'd like to avoid the noisy clicking sound, so I'm trying to use some kind of BJT transistor or MOSFET based approach.

It might be relevant that pin 16 has a [10k pull up resistor](https://github.com/raphaelbs/esp32-cam-ai-thinker/blob/master/docs/esp32cam-pin-notes.md#gpio16---u2rxd-useless-gpio).

(This is part of a more complex setup, and I only have pin 16 left.)

There is 5v on the breadboard power rail, and 3.3v appears on the output pin when turned on HIGH.

### Maybe could work

I tried using and NPN transistor (2N2222A) as a switch, but that didn't turn on the SIM800L.

I was following [this kind of setup](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/554443/esp32-and-moisture-sensor-transistor-switch) and maybe that wasn't suitable?

### Approaches that didn't work

#### IRF530N MOSFET

As @vir [explains](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/619449/312261): **The 3.3V from the module is not enough to turn on the IRF530, which has a threshold voltage of 2-4V.**

I wired it up like below, but HIGH on GPIO 16 doesn't turn on the SIM800L.

Can this possibly work?

There was [another question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/579801/esp32-gpio-not-turning-on-mosfet-completely) where someone got a similar mosfet to work, and I saw a breakout-board with this on/off function which used an IRF520.

[This guide](https://arduinodiy.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/using-mosfets-with-ttl-levels/) also indicates some techniques but honestly it's over my head how the pieces might have to fit together to make it work.

[image: esp32 with mosfet]

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3PkpOeHTnfo) where he includes this diagram:

[image]

Comment: What voltage does your ESP32 output on that pin? Probably not high enough to turn on an IRF530; that FET isn't rated for less than 10 V drive.

Comment: The SIM800L seems to be powered by 3.8V to 4.2V, is this correct? What is the power supply connected to the breadboard? Do you have higher voltage available with the same reference?

Comment: Thanks, I extended the description

Comment: So, I'm assuming neither a higher voltage (e.g. 12V) is available with the same reference nor the power supply specs for the SIM800L module are known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the IRF530N was that its gate voltage is too high (~4v) for the ESP32 pin signal (3.3v) to open it.

I replaced it with an IRLZ24NPBF, [the datasheet](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/infineon-technologies/IRLZ24NPBF/811787) says Vgs 2v.

This FET did open with the lower voltage, but when drain and source was connected to the power rail (5v), some voltage was lost in the FET and only 4v appeared on the SIM800L, which is not quite enough.

Connecting the FET to a 9v battery worked.

The FET however stays open even with LOW signal from the ESP32 pin. It only turns off when the ESP32 goes into deep sleep.

- ESP32 on: 6-7v on the SIM800L
- ESP32 in deep sleep: 3v and 60µA on the SIM800L

(This is acceptable for my use case, as I wanted the SIM800L not to draw battery power while the ESP32 is sleeping.)

I tried to control the FET gate with a BJT transistor, using the ESP32 pin to open/close the BJT, but then again the FET doesn't open enough to drive the SIM800L (or it doesn't get enough current?).

So this works to the extent that ESP32 on normal power turns the SIM800L on, and deep sleep turns it off:

[image: circuit]

Answer (score 1):

The 3.3V from the module is not enough to turn on the IRF530, which has a threshold voltage of 2-4V.  5V should be enough, which gives you options.  You could change the IRF530 for another device (BJT, 3.3V logic level MOSFET) that will work directly from a 3.3V signal or add in a cheap gate driver chip that will apply 5V to the gate of the IRF530.  It might not be a great idea to low-side switch the SIM800L so a small SSR or PMOS with appropriate gate driver could be indicated here.

Comment: 5 V is not going to be anywhere *near* enough to fully enhance an IRF530. You generally want two or three times the threshold voltage to turn it on.

Comment: Agreed.  The datasheet shows a 4.5V Vgs curve that looks not-great but might be able to control a low current load.  A gate driver with integrated charge pump would guarantee good channel enhancement but that's becoming more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @vir even if that modem spikes to 2A? Because yes, that's how high GPRS modems do sometimes. I unfortunately don't remember the pulse width.

Comment: @JanDorniak The same figures I've found. Not to mention the incompatible voltage.

Comment: Possible, but I recommend high side switching over trying to make the IRF530 work.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps this could be approached more generally about turning the modem on/off? I renamed and edited the question. I tried the BJT method [like this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/554443/esp32-and-moisture-sensor-transistor-switch) but perhaps didn't do it right. I have BC547C, BC557C, and 2N2222A at hand.

Comment: Could it be as simple as changing the mosfet? The local store has IRLZ24NPBF, [the datasheet](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/infineon-technologies/IRLZ24NPBF/811787) says Vgs 2v

Comment: You could use the BC547 to pull the gate of a logic level P-channel MOSFET down from 5V.

Comment: @vir I can't uncompress that concise advice... but I got a IRLZ24NPBF now, which is logic-level, although n-channel. I replaced the IRF530, and it works to some extent: gate connected to pin 16, when the ESP32-CAM is on, the MOSFET turns on the SIM800L. It stays on even with the pin set to LOW, but it turns off when the ESP32-CAM enters deep sleep. Also, the MOSFET driver circuit had to be connected to a 9v battery, the 5v power rail was not enough (perhaps some voltage is lost in the MOSFET).